# Fail to deploy to local tomcat Spring boot 3.1

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven, tomcat

I'm very green in the backend part of the business, and i can't figure it out why i can't make my application work.

It is a simple WebHook fetcher from a JSON in Postman.
Tested with postman it works when started it in localhost:8080 with Spring, it doesn't when i put the .war into the tomcat server.
In order to create the .war file i use `mvn clean install` or `./mvn clean package`
The terminal response to the second command is this one:

```
   Plugin validation issues were detected in 1 plugin(s)
  * org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-plugin:3.2.2
```

Could that be why tomcat does not work? could be an issue with my code?
Tomcat version is 9.0.78
Application.properties is empty.

This is my pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
   <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
   <parent>
       <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
       <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
       <version>3.1.1</version>
       <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
   </parent>
   <groupId>test.gio</groupId>
   <artifactId>TestFinal</artifactId>
   <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
   <packaging>war</packaging>
   <name>TestFinal</name>
   <description>Demo project for webhook</description>
   <properties>
       <java.version>17</java.version>
   </properties>
   <dependencies>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
           <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
           <scope>provided</scope>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
           <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
           <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
           <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
           <scope>runtime</scope>
       </dependency>
        <dependency>
           <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
           <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
           <scope>provided</scope>
           <version>9.0.75</version>
       </dependency>

       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
           <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
           <optional>true</optional>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
           <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
           <scope>test</scope>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
           <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
           <version>2.15.2</version>
       </dependency>
   </dependencies>

   <build>
       <finalName>TestFinal</finalName>
       <plugins>
           <plugin>
               <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
               <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
               <configuration>
                   <excludes>
                       <exclude>
                           <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                           <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                       </exclude>
                   </excludes>
               </configuration>
           </plugin>
           <plugin>
               <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
               <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
               <version>3.2.2</version>
               <configuration>
                   <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
               </configuration>
           </plugin>
       </plugins>
   </build>

</project>
```

My controller.java:

```
@RestController
public class WebHookController {

    @PostMapping("/webhook")
    public ResponseEntity<String> webhook(@RequestBody OrderPayload orderPayload) {
        System.out.println("Webhook received!");
        orderPayloadService.processOrderPayload(orderPayload);
        return ResponseEntity.ok("Webhook received! Sei un grande :)");
    }

  @GetMapping("/hello")
    public String hello()
    {
        return "Hello User, have a nice day.";
    }
}
```

My Application.java:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class TestFinalApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application)
    {
        return application.sources(TestFinalApplication.class);
    }
    @RequestMapping("/TestFinal")
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(TestFinalApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

And my servletinitializer.java:

```
public class ServletInitializer extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(TestFinalApplication.class);
    }

}
```

Can you tell me what i did wrong i am very desperate

Comment: Remove the war plugin.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spring boot 3.0.1 application not running on tomcat9 external server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75017269/spring-boot-3-0-1-application-not-running-on-tomcat9-external-server)

Comment: i removed the war plugin and changed to tomcat 10 but still just work in my machine

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're using Tomcat 9.0.x [which supports Servlet 4.0](https://tomcat.apache.org/whichversion.html) and Spring Boot 3.x which requires a Servlet 5.0+ compatible container. You will have to use Tomcat 10.1 if you want to be able to deploy a Spring Boot 3 application to it.

Comment: now i got this error:   `12-Jul-2023 10:33:22.183 SEVERE [RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke Exception invoking method [manageApp]
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error starting child`   is this what progress feels like?

Answer (score 0):

i removed this dependecy in my pom.xml file:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
        <version>9.0.75</version>
    </dependency>
```

And it worked!