# Cannot connect to SpringBoot Websocket application

Tags: spring-boot, tomcat, websocket

I built a very simple SpringBoot websocket application to practice communication with the STOMP protocol. I also built a client.

This client works well with the SpringBoot server whenever I start the server in the IntelliJ - I can connect to the server.

However if I am deploying to a Tomcat 9 container, the connection is not possible anymore. In the access logs of the server I am finding error 302.

Server configuration is as follows:

```
<Service name="planeswsserver">
    <Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
           connectionTimeout="20000"
           maxParameterCount="1000"
           />
    <Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost">
      <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.LockOutRealm">
        <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm"
           resourceName="UserDatabase"/>
      </Realm>

      <Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps"
        unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">

        <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs"
           prefix="localhost_access_log" suffix=".txt"
           pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" />
      </Host>
    </Engine>
  </Service>
```

Can anyone please give me a hint in the right direction ?

Comment: I think the solution lies in this ticket https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75017269/spring-boot-3-0-1-application-not-running-on-tomcat9-external-server